# Kernel 5.15 not really fixing the suspend problem in amd laptops? Or I am doing something wrong?

Tags: kernel, suspend

First of all my laptop is hp envy x360 13 inch, with ryzen 5 3500 u. My kernel is now 5.15.0-051500-generic.

As soon as I saw that there is a fix for s0ix state for amd laptops in the new kernel I installed it. I can confirm that I have installed the kernel correctly by typing "uname -r", it shows up... Yet for some reason the suspend still doesn't work. The led turns off, the screen switches off, the fan is not spinning fortunately, and only hard reset can get me out of this doomed state.

Has anyone seen similar behavior after installing that kernel? If you did succeed in making the suspend work, what did you do exactly?

EDIT: Also now I discovered that hitting the power button while it's in this weird state, starts up the fan and a weird sound plays, definitely ubuntu sound. It is a very nice sound. Then hard reset.

EDIT2: so journal ctl for shutdown has this

```
lis 02 06:57:25 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx systemd[1]:
Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Subject: A start job for unit grub-initrd-fallback.service has        begun execution
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

    A start job for unit grub-initrd-fallback.service has begun execution.

The job identifier is 1685.
lis 02 06:57:25 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Subject: Unit succeeded
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit grub-initrd-fallback.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
lis 02 06:57:25 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Subject: A start job for unit grub-initrd-fallback.service has finished successfully
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
A start job for unit grub-initrd-fallback.service has finished successfully.

The job identifier is 1685.
```

Then journal for the startup:

```
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: Linux version 5.15.0-051500-generic (kernel@sita) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubun>
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-051500-generic root=UUID=466f1fc9-e29a-4896-897d-36f04961292b ro quiet >
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: signal: max sigframe size: 1776
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000003ffffff] usablelis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000004000000-0x000000000400afff] ACPI NVS
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000400b000-0x0000000009ecffff] usable
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009ed0000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x0000000057b62fff] usable
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000057b63000-0x0000000057c8afff] reserved
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000057c8b000-0x0000000057d11fff] ACPI data
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000057d12000-0x0000000058282fff] ACPI NVS
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000058283000-0x000000005db13fff] reserved
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005db14000-0x000000005effffff] usable
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000005f000000-0x00000000dfffffff] reserved
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
lis 02 06:58:18 jan-HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-13-ar0xxx kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
```

Now for the `man pm-is-supported` it just says there aren't any manual entries.
Also I didn't create any swap space since I figured that is needed for hibernation and what I wanted is to reach suspend to ram.

Comment: Look at the shutdown logs `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -xe` and startup logs `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -x`. Read `man journalctl sudo`. [Edit] your question and show `free`. Do you have swap space?

Comment: Read `man pm-is-supported`.